# Using guard live reload and guard compass seems to conflict

Tags: compass-sass, guard, livereload

I'm trying to use guard livereload and guard compass together. Here is my file

## A sample Guardfile

```
    # More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

    guard 'compass' do
      watch('^sass/(.*)\.s[ac]ss')
    end

    guard 'livereload' do
      watch(%r{.+\.(css|html|js)$})
    end

    # This will concatenate the javascript files specified in :files to public/js/all.js
    #guard :concat, type: "js", files: %w(), input_dir: "public/js", output: "public/js/all"

    #guard :concat, type: "css", files: %w(), input_dir: "public/css", output: "public/css/all"

    #guard 'uglify', :destination_file => "public/javascripts/application.js" do
    #  watch (%r{app/assets/javascripts/application.js})
    #end
```

When i begin to guard, without enabling the chrome live reload extension, my sass files are compiled and work well.

But when I enable the livereload extension, my terminal says that browser is connected, and then when i make changes in my sass files, nothing happens (neither the page reloads, nor the sass files are compiled).

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, I'm lauching two terminals in windows, one where I do compass watch, and one where I do guard (I commented the compass part of the GuardFile).

If someone has a better solution

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it and works perfectly.

```
    puts "Using default guard file."

group :development do

  if File.exists?("./config.rb")
    # Compile on start.
    puts `compass compile --time --quiet`
    # https://github.com/guard/guard-compass
    guard :compass do
      watch(%r{(.*)\.s[ac]ss$})
    end
  end

  guard :livereload, :host => '127.0.0.1', :port => '35729', :grace_period => 0.5 do
    watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html?|php|inc|theme)$})
  end

end
```

All this does is tells Compass where my config.rb is... Which is in the base of my site where my Guardfile is kept. Then it has compass compile the SCSS. 
Not sure about your situation but in mine I needed to set the host and port for it to work smoothly. But basically guard will watch for a change and once compass outputs the css file LiveReload notices the change and then reloads that file. Pretty simple.

Im sure you know already but add all the correct Gems to your Gemfile, run 'bundle' on your project and then initiate Guard using $ guard

In your browser make sure you hit the LiveReload button and it will tell you in the terminal that browser is connected and away you go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, not this good. I think the problem is not about the livereaload feature. If I have to task running with guard, I will have the same behaviour. So basically if I have sass and grunt running through guard, the guard console will freeze or bug :s.